How can i add badge on tabbar in maui android
I've tried to add badge in iOS. I'm able to add successfully. Can someone please help in android. Please not that i don't want to use shell navigation.
   [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public abstract class AppTabbedPageBase : TabbedPage, IViewModelTypeExposed
{
    protected AppTabbedPageBase()
    {
        //Uncomment this if you need to implement custom navigation bar.
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, true);
    }

    public abstract Type ViewModelType { get; }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
        base.OnHandlerChanged();

     #if ANDROID

        FieldInfo tabbedPageManagerFieldInfo = typeof(TabbedPage).GetField("_tabbedPageManager", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        object tabbedPageManager = tabbedPageManagerFieldInfo?.GetValue(this);

        FieldInfo tabLayoutFieldInfo = tabbedPageManager?.GetType().GetField("_tabLayout", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        var tablayout = tabLayoutFieldInfo?.GetValue(tabbedPageManager) as Google.Android.Material.Tabs.TabLayout;

        if (tablayout != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < tablayout.TabCount; i++)
            {
                tablayout.GetTabAt(i).OrCreateBadge.Number = 10;

                //  tablayout.GetTabAt(i).OrCreateBadge.BackgroundColor = Resource.Color.blue;

                //   tablayout.GetTabAt(i).OrCreateBadge.BadgeTextColor = Resource.Color.white;

            }

        }
      #endif
    }


}

============
<views:MainTabbedPageXaml
x:Class="Demo.UI.MainTabbedPage">
<NavigationPage IconImageSource="navhome.png" Title="Home">
    <x:Arguments>
        <views:HomePage BindingContext="{Binding HomeViewModel}" />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>

<NavigationPage IconImageSource="navcart.png" Title="Cart">
    <x:Arguments>
        <views:CartPage BindingContext="{Binding CartViewModel}" />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>

<NavigationPage IconImageSource="navmap.png" Title="Maps">
    <x:Arguments>
        <views:MapsPage BindingContext="{Binding MapsViewModel}" />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
<NavigationPage IconImageSource="navprofile.png" Title="Profile">
    <x:Arguments>
        <views:ProfilePage BindingContext="{Binding ProfileViewModel}" />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>

</views:MainTabbedPageXaml>
Not sure, how can i access tablayout and add badge over there.

You can modify it by using platform native code.
From the source code of TabbedPage.Android.cs, we can first get the instance of TabbedPageManager,and from the source code of TabbedPageManager, we can use Reflection to get TabbedPageManager (because it is a internal class) and TabLayout.
Then we can override method OnHandlerChanged() on the TabbedPage.
Please refer to the following code:
#if ANDROID
using System.Reflection;
#endif


public partial class HomeTabbedPage : TabbedPage
{
      public HomeTabbedPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }

    protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
        base.OnHandlerChanged();

#if ANDROID

            FieldInfo tabbedPageManagerFieldInfo = typeof(TabbedPage).GetField("_tabbedPageManager", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

            object tabbedPageManager = tabbedPageManagerFieldInfo?.GetValue(this);

            FieldInfo tabLayoutFieldInfo = tabbedPageManager?.GetType().GetField("_tabLayout", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

            var tablayout = tabLayoutFieldInfo?.GetValue(tabbedPageManager) as Google.Android.Material.Tabs.TabLayout;

            if (tablayout != null)   
            {    
                for (int i = 0; i < tablayout.TabCount; i++)   
                {    
                    tablayout.GetTabAt(i).OrCreateBadge.Number = 10;

                  //  tablayout.GetTabAt(i).OrCreateBadge.BackgroundColor = Resource.Color.blue;

                 //   tablayout.GetTabAt(i).OrCreateBadge.BadgeTextColor = Resource.Color.white;

                }

            }
#endif
    }
}

And the following screenshot is the result on my side:


Hii @Jessie , I'm getting tablayout null using your code

Hi @VanjaraSweta, did you use it as I said? The code I shared works properly on my side.

And I also shared a screenshot of the running result on my side to my answer. You can check it.

yes @jessie. I used same code

var tabLayout = tabLayoutFieldInfo?.GetValue(tabbedPageManager) as Google.Android.Material.Tabs.TabLayout;
I'm getting tablayoutfieldInfo but not getting tablayout

can you share your sample if possible?   @Jessie Zhang -MSFT

I don't have any other code ,I'm just overriding the OnHandlerChanged method in TabbedPage. I have added all my TabbedPage code to my answer. You can check it.

Due to policy restrictions, we have strict control over the upload of the entire demo. If your problem is still not solved, you can upload  a basic demo here and we can help you check it out. :)

I updated my code. Can you please check and let me know what i did wrong?

I noticed that the class AppTabbedPageBase   is abstract class which cannot be instantiated.  You can try to override the OnHandlerChanged method directly in class MainTabbedPage.

I tried. same result.

Could you please post a basic demo here so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?

I found the issue, if i added    android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom" then tabbedlayout getting null otherwise working fine. can you please check?

Thanks. I've fixed it. @jessie :)
